# What does the Android Design guide say about expanding/collapsing ListView items depending on Switch

Tags: android, android-switch

I have a settings oriented application for both Android and iOS and I'm currently implementing a new feature.

In my iOS application, I have a List of different settings and among them is a switch. When the switch is OFF, some list rows (or none) are shown and when the switch is ON, some *other* list rows are shown.

When I browsed through Android's Settings menu, I noticed that the pattern seems to be to disable settings rows instead of hiding them, depending on the switch state (ON / OFF).

The behaviour I'm looking for is similar to the Android settings menu where the user disables the Wifi and all Wifi settings disappear, but I want to do this for specific rows in the list and not on the whole "page" / "view".

Is there anything in Android's style guides that says I shouldn't hide / show list rows depending on a switch?

[image]

iOS application Switch ON and 3 corresponding rows.

[image]

iOS application Switch OFF and 2 corresponding rows.

[image]

Android Settings menu Switch OFF and disabled row (Android Beam) that is not disabled if the switch is ON.

Observe that I'm not looking for options, but what Android's style guide (Lollipop+ and design compat) says about this.

Answer (score 0):

Since android 6.0 was published the old (5.0-android) docs seem not be available any more.  i have found a mirror here by searching "docs/design/patterns/settings.html" which is part of my local sdk-doc:

http://soft.smkmuh5babat.sch.id/IDE/Android-SDK-TKJ/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702/sdk/docs/design/patterns/settings.html

there are both variants "Master on/off switch" that removes options and "Dependency" that disables the options.